# Template driven form validation for From Date and To Date

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to add validation for from date and to date controls in  template driven form.how can i validate them such as "from date should be greater than to date"and vise versa.
Also i am thinking to reuse this validation throughout my application for different from date and to date controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function that takes in two form controls. Compare the dates, and on error, set the errors of the form controls :

```js
compareDates(from: FormControl, to: FormControl) {
  const startDate: Date = ConvertYourFormValueToValidDate(from.value);
  const endDate: Date = ConvertYourFormValueToValidDate(to.value);

  if (startDate.getTime() > endDate.getTime()) {
    from.setErrors({ ...from.errors, 'aboveEnd': true });
  } else if (startDate.getTime() > endDate.getTime()) {
    to.setErrors({ ...to.errors, 'belowStart': true });
  }
}
```

Comment: As a side note, I didn't put the `else` condition : I'll let you make it, so that it erases both errors on both form controls.

Comment: And template driven forms use form controls. Validation is bound to form controls (or form groups). If you think that `[(ngModel)]` means "template driven", you're mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

So if you use tempalte driven forms you have an ngModel on your date-input. For validation you could check the value of your date-model and validate it. To know if your model changes you could use ngModelChange.

Comment: This should be a comment (And it doesn't really answer the question)

Comment: yeah but is it possible to make a directive common for all the start date and end date controls in my application?

Comment: @akhilanair you should take a look at my answer for that "directive". The function I gave should apply to any form control that you pass to it, making it reusable everywhere.

Comment: as for the OP of this answer, next time you're commenting on my answer, consider leaving your comments, even though you're wrong : a lot of people don't know the difference with two-way binding and template-driven forms, and this could have helped them too.

Comment: @trichetriche Thank you.will try for sure

Answer (score 1):

JS [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) can be compared using `<` and `>`

```js
fromDate = new Date() // today
toDate = new Date(fromDate.valueOf() + 60*60*24) // tomorrow

function toDateIsLater(fromDate, toDate) {
  return toDate > fromDate
}

console.log(toDateIsLater(fromDate, toDate))
```